# A/B Testing in Dialogflow (within the same agent)

Tags: dialogflow-es, ab-testing

I'm wondering whether we can proceed A/B Testing in Dialogflow within the same agent? E.G. User A talks to Ver. A and User B to Ver.B in order to test which one performs better.

Can I work it out within "Environment & Vesioning"? Thanks.

[image: Environment & Versioning]

Answer (score 1):

There is no A/B testing within the same agent as of now but you can have 2 separate agents with separate sets of test users. For example set up alpha tests for each of the 2 agents and add separate user sets, a description on how to do this can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments).

Keep in mind that you can't publish 2 agents with the same name.

To make this easier you can export your agent and import it into a new project, this option can be found in the Dialogflow settings. Then change only the intents that you want to test.

Comment: Thanks Lisa! Your suggestions help a lot! Appreciated it.  I was wondering whether the "Environment & Versioning" could perform the A/B testing but just learned from you that it didn't work for Dialogflow atm.